# Using JLayer (AKA JavaLayer) to analyze mp3 files in java?

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer

I would like to perform a FFT on frames of an MP3 file using Java (think spectrum analyzer). I found [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) which seems to fit the requirement of MP3 Decoding, but I'm not sure how to use it (Most examples are simply players that use the higher level helper, but that's not what I am looking for). FFT seems easy compared to decoding MP3 files ;)

My question is basically this: How would I take an MP3 file in java, and decode it to raw audio data for analysis in Java using JLayer

Answer (score 2):

I am on the same Boat - trying to decode and analyze MP3 files using Java. You may want to check out MP3 SPI from the same author. There is a good example of getting the raw decoded PCM data from an MP3 file in his page:

http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html

Good luck,
Uri